# The need of multiplicity of theories

Tags: philosophy-of-science, history

I know why we may need multiplicity of theories in science. But, I am not sure why we may need it for history or why we may not need it for science. Upon this, I have a couple of questions:

1) What is the necessity of many theories in history to understand our world?
2) What are some examples that demonstrates this?
3) Why may we not need multiplicity of theories in science? and what could be some examples that proves this?
4) What is the actual process of historians forming perspectives as they are coming up with theories?

It would be really thoughtful if anyone could help me out and give me some in-depth answers! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by "different theories" in the context of history? (I don't really know what a "theory" means, precisely, in the "qualitative" social sciences or humanities.)

Comment: different theories refer to historical theories
a theory can be defined as a set of analytical principles designed to structure our observation and explanation

Comment: Again, that's rather unclear to me - can you give an *example* of what you mean?

Comment: ex) Marxist theory

Comment: See [Historicist Theories of Scientific Rationality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/rationality-historicist/).

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the checkmark to reward the contributor.